# VLOOKUP with variable first column

Tags: google-sheets

Error: "Did not find value '1' in VLOOKUP evaluation."

In the example I'm trying to lookup `1` and retrieve `aa` but get the error above. Ideally I'd like a non-script solution. Thanks.

B1: =LEFT(C1,1). Copied down to B2...B3

C1:C3:

2 b

1 aa

4 d

D1: =VLOOKUP($F$1,($B$1:$C$3),2)

F1: 1

[Sample sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1EjJWxZp9yBU16WH8mPs6eM5GLNaS47IrV7N0gXvquoE)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you're looking for number in a text. Numbers are aligned right. Text is aligned left. Since B1 is already a number, but just seen by Google as text, you simply multiply it by 1 to convert text to number.

```
  B1: =(LEFT(C1,1))*1
```

Or you convert F1 to text by

```
  F1=  '1
```

Or

```
=VLOOKUP(TEXT ($F$1,"0"),($B$1:$C$3),2,false)
```

Answer (score 0):

You only columns C and F. You can use split to sepatate column C like this:

```
=arrayformula(vlookup(F1,split(C1:C3," "),2,false))
```

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap each first column value in `VALUE()` to make them numeric.